# Troubles searching xml document with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an xml document that has 3 elements in this format:

```
<Codes>
    <Code>
        <CodeScenario>3</CodeScenario>
        <CodeScenario>4</CodeScenario>
        <CodeScenario>6</CodeScenario>
        <CodeScenario>7</CodeScenario>
        <CodeCategory>Category3</CodeCategory>
        <CodeID>043</CodeID>
        <CodeDescription>Description3</CodeDescription>
        <CodeType>PE</CodeType>
        </Code>
    <Code>
        <CodeCategory>Category2</CodeCategory>
        <CodeID>046</CodeID>
        <CodeDescription>Description2</CodeDescription>
        <CodeType>PE</CodeType>
    </Code>
    <Code>
        <CodeScenario>2</CodeScenario>
        <CodeCategory>Category1</CodeCategory>
        <CodeID>100</CodeID>
        <CodeDescription>Description1</CodeDescription>
        <CodeType>PR</CodeType>
    </Code>
</Codes>
```

I'd like to be able to use a linq query to tell me if a code element has a codetype based on ID. This is what I've come up with so far. It works but it's ugly and I'd prefer to use dot notation if possible. Can anybody help me out?

```
public bool HasCodeType(string CodeType, string Code)
{
    var QueryResult = (from descendant in XMLdocument.Descendants("Code")
                       from type in descendant.Elements("CodeType")
                       where type != null &&
                             type.Value.Equals(CodeType)
                       select new { CID = descendant.Element("CodeID").Value }).Distinct();

    foreach (var result in QueryResult)
    {
        if (Code == result.CID)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd give us *complete* XML rather than just an incomplete snippet (no values!)

Comment: i added a more complete xml sample

Comment: Okay... and have you tried the code in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably simplest to find the `CodeType` first, then go "up and down":

```
// Note camelCase for variable names, not PascalCase.
var query = document.Descendants("CodeType")
                    .Where(type => type.Value == codeType)
                    .Select(type => (string) type.Parent.Element("CodeID"))
                    .Where(id => id == null)
                    .Distinct();
```

The second `Where` clause is to avoid getting `null` values for `CodeType` elements with no sibling `CodeID` element.

If all you're doing with the query is checking for the presence of the given ID though, you don't need to go to all that trouble:

```
return document.Descendants("Code")
               .Any(code => (string) code.Element("CodeType") == codeType &&
                            (string) code.Element("CodeID") == codeId));
```

*Really* simple.

Comment: Perfect. The simple solution is all i needed. Thank You!